# Отображение изображения в picture box

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, изображения

Есть программа на winforms. С помощью codefirst создана таблица. Вот модель:

```
public class Auto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    }
```

А вот код записи в базу изображения и вытягивание её оттуда.

```
//Сохранение в базу
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db = new Context();
            byte[] imageData;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                imageData = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            }

            Auto auto = new Auto { Mark = "Dodge", Picture = imageData };
            db.Cars.Add(auto);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Dispose();
        }

//Чтение из базы

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db = new Context();
            Auto auto = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault();
            byte[] picture = auto.Picture;

            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(picture));
        }
```

Но у изображения размер 1920х1080, я как-то могу изменить размер в программе? Чтобы окно формы не растягивать на весь экран, чтобы увидеть картинку полностью? Или нужно изначально качать картинку нужного размера?
И вторая часть вопроса, посмотрел пример на метаните, там читается Image не из потока а по-другому, вот пример оттуда:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=usersdb;Integrated Security=True";
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Images";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string filename = reader.GetString(1);
            string title = reader.GetString(2);
            byte[] data = (byte[])reader.GetValue(3);

            Image image = new Image(id, filename, title, data);
            images.Add(image);
        }
    }
```

Но если я делаю так же:

```
db = new Context();
            Auto auto = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault();
            byte[] picture = auto.Picture;

            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(picture));
            Image image = new Image(1, "auto", auto.Mark, auto.Picture);
```

То у меня ошибка:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Drawing.Image'

То есть на вторую часть вопроса я, в принципе, нашёл альтернативу, но хотелось бы узнать, как это тоже работает, ведь я думаю на метаните рабочий пример, но я что-то делаю не так. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: На метаните используется свой собственный класс `Image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чтобы окно формы не растягивать на весь экран, чтобы увидеть картинку полностью?

У контрола PictureBox есть свойство SizeMode. Выставляете StretchImage.
Подробнее:
[здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.16.php)